# How can I script changing DNS settings for my WiFi connection on startup?

Tags: networking, dns, vpn

My VPN software (Forticlient) breaks DNS and I get that question mark over the WiFi symbol and no internet. I can fix it by deleting all the DNS IPs, setting DNS to auto and restarting networking. I can't change VPN as it's necessary for my job so how do I script this to happen on startup?

Comment: Can you not just leave the DNS set at auto all the time?

Comment: @David that only works if Forticlient (which is a fortinet vpn client that is SEPARATE from Network Manager and such) knows to go back and reset the DNS settings.  If it is not using network/resolved to handle that, and is instead overwriting /etc/resolv.conf then there's no way to *script* that easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a bash script using nmcli to automate DNS config and added it to the startup programs. It works.

```
#!/bin/bash

# ignore the DHCP DNS settinggs
nmcli c modify <SSID> ipv4.ignore-auto-dns yes

# set the DNS
nmcli c modify <SSID> ipv4.dns "1.1.1.3, 1.0.0.3"

# just toggle the connection
nmcli con down <SSID>
nmcli con up <SSID>
```